# j2se製のアプリをandroidやios上で動かしたい。

Tags: ios, android, java

昔swingで書いたゲームプログラムがあるのですが、それをモバイルに移植したいです。

例えば、androidやios上で動く、j2se（j2me?）互換のjvmなどがあれば、可能かと思っているのですが、そういったプロダクトはあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく無いと思います。ロジック部分を再利用するようにUIを作り直すのが、近道かもしれません。

参考まで

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android

http://webbyit.blogspot.jp/2012/01/swing-to-android.html